# How to get a value from a dcitionary if a condition is met?

Tags: python

Let's suppose I want to get the respective value for the key activation (see code below). The problem is that, for getting the value for the activation = "relu" the dictionary will calculate also the values for the others keys which I don't want due to time constraints. Is there any way to get just the value I pretend for one particular key without wasting time defining the complete dictionary without if conditions?

```
def get_analytical_derivatives(self, hi, activation):
     dact_dhi ={
         'leaky_relu' : 2*hi,
         'relu' : 2*hi**2,
         'softplus' : 1
         }
```

Comment: Why are you using dictionary here?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't need to be a dictionary. I'm using it because I'm sending to a class a string correspondent to the key. It could be a list, however the problem remains right?

Comment: Simply using if-else statements seems sufficient and efficient to me. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: No, just the question that I can have a lot of keys, so a lot of if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid unnecessary calculations, then you can use anonymous functions i.e. `lambda`.

```
def get_analytical_derivatives(self, hi, activation):
    dact_dhi ={
        'leaky_relu' : lambda : 2*hi,
        'relu' : lambda : 2*hi**2,
        'softplus' : lambda : 1
    }
    return dact_dhi[activation]()
```

Probably, there are better ways to do that, but I don't know much about what you're doing, so my options are limited.